# How to horizontally pivot a table in python that also has multiple columns of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, pivot

Currently I have a table in this format :

```
  Ticker  Financial Ratio                  2001     2002    2003    
  ARKR    Net Profit Margin                -0.1931  0.052   -0.0187
  ARKR    Return on Assets                 0        0       0
  ARKR    Current Ratio                    1.3419     1.2096  0.7031
  ARMK    Net Profit Margin                -0.1931  0.052   -0.0187
  ARMK    Return on Assets                 0        0       0
  ARMK    Current Ratio                    1.3419     1.2096  0.7031
```

I would like this to be converted to :

```
  Ticker  2001 Net Profit Margin  2001 Return on Assets  2001 Current Ratio  2002 Net Profit Margin...
  ARKR    -0.1931                 0                      1.3419              0.052  
  ARMK    -0.1931                 0                      1.3419              0.052
```

Only keeping ticker vertical

Code I have so far:

```
  pre_horizontal_df = pd.read_csv('database_raw.csv')
  pre_horizontal_df['period'] = pre_horizontal_df.2001.astype(str)
  df1 = pre_horizontal_df.groupby(['ticker']).unstack()
  print (df1)
```

But I know this is not correct. Can this horizontal pivot be done in python df / pandas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `DataFrame.pivot`, just skip defining `values=`:

```py
out = df.pivot(index="Ticker", columns="Financial Ratio")
out.columns = [f"{year} {desc}" for year, desc in out.columns]
print(out.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
  Ticker  2001 Current Ratio  2001 Net Profit Margin  2001 Return on Assets  2002 Current Ratio  2002 Net Profit Margin  2002 Return on Assets  2003 Current Ratio  2003 Net Profit Margin  2003 Return on Assets
0   ARKR              1.3419                 -0.1931                    0.0              1.2096                   0.052                    0.0              0.7031                 -0.0187                    0.0
1   ARMK              1.3419                 -0.1931                    0.0              1.2096                   0.052                    0.0              0.7031                 -0.0187                    0.0
```